# Merge objects within array dynamically

Tags: javascript, object

I was unable to reproduce the merge as this popular answer: [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically). However, I do not see my situation as significantly different than the OP. For illustration's sake, here is my data structure:

```
var tempList1 = [
   {'manager':'John', 'x1':0, 'y1':0, 'x2':1, 'y2':1},
   {'manager':'Julie', 'x1':0, 'y1':0, 'x2':1, 'y2':1},
...
];

var tempList2 = [
   {'manager':'John', 'x3':0, 'y3':0, 'x4':1, 'y4':1},
   {'manager':'Julie', 'x3':0, 'y3':0, 'x4':1, 'y4':1},
...
];
```

The desired result after merge is:

```
var combinedList = [
    {'manager':'John', 'x1':0, 'y1':0, 'x2':1, 'y2':1, 'x3':0, 'y3':0, 'x4':1, 'y4':1},
    {'manager':'Julie', 'x1':0, 'y1':0, 'x2':1, 'y2':1, 'x3':0, 'y3':0, 'x4':1, 'y4':1}
];
```

My attempt was:

```
          var combinedList = [];
          for (var k = 0; k < managerList.length; k++)
              let merged = {...tempList1[k],...tempList2[k]}
              combinedList.push(merged);

              console.log(combinedList)
```

But that gave me the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Lexical declaration cannot appear in a
>   single-statement context

### Question

How should I adjust my code so I can combine each object in my array (as seen above)?

Comment: You forgot to put brackets around the `for` block. Fix that, and your code works

Comment: Are you coming from python by any chance? ;)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Fixed thanks. and yea, I'm guilty of python background!